# Apache Spark's RDD[Vector] Immutability issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I know the RDDs are immutable and therefore their value cannot be changed but I see the following behaviour:

I wrote an implementation for FuzzyCMeans (https://github.com/salexln/FinalProject_FCM) algorithm and now I'm testing it, so I run the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.FuzzyCMeans
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val data = sc.textFile("/home/development/myPrjects/R/butterfly/butterfly.txt")
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
> parsedData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at <console>:31

val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 20


parsedData.foreach{ point => println(point) }
> [0.0,-8.0]
[-3.0,-2.0]
[-3.0,0.0]
[-3.0,2.0]
[-2.0,-1.0]
[-2.0,0.0]
[-2.0,1.0]
[-1.0,0.0]
[0.0,0.0]
[1.0,0.0]
[2.0,-1.0]
[2.0,0.0]
[2.0,1.0]
[3.0,-2.0]
[3.0,0.0]
[3.0,2.0]
[0.0,8.0] 

val clusters = FuzzyCMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIteration
parsedData.foreach{ point => println(point) }
> 
[0.0,-0.4803333185624595]
[-0.1811743096972924,-0.12078287313152826]
[-0.06638890786148487,0.0]
[-0.04005925925925929,0.02670617283950619]
[-0.12193263222069807,-0.060966316110349035]
[-0.0512,0.0]
[NaN,NaN]
[-0.049382716049382706,0.0]
[NaN,NaN]
[0.006830134553650707,0.0]
[0.05120000000000002,-0.02560000000000001]
[0.04755220304297078,0.0]
[0.06581619798335057,0.03290809899167529]
[0.12010867103812725,-0.0800724473587515]
[0.10946638900458144,0.0]
[0.14814814814814817,0.09876543209876545]
[0.0,0.49119985188436205]
```

But how can this be that my method changes the Immutable RDD?

BTW, the signature of the train method, is the following:

train( data: RDD[Vector], clusters: Int, maxIterations: Int)

Comment: Could you accept one of the answer or explain why these doesn't work for you so these can be improved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is precisely described in [the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd):

> Printing elements of an RDD
>
> Another common idiom is attempting to print out the elements of an RDD
>   using rdd.foreach(println) or rdd.map(println). On a single machine,
>   this will generate the expected output and print all the RDD’s
>   elements. However, in cluster mode, the output to stdout being called
>   by the executors is now writing to the executor’s stdout instead, not
>   the one on the driver, so stdout on the driver won’t show these! To
>   print all elements on the driver, one can use the collect() method to
>   first bring the RDD to the driver node thus:
>   rdd.collect().foreach(println). This can cause the driver to run out
>   of memory, though, because collect() fetches the entire RDD to a
>   single machine; if you only need to print a few elements of the RDD, a
>   safer approach is to use the take(): rdd.take(100).foreach(println).

So, as data can migrate between nodes, the same output of `foreach` is not guaranteed. RDD is immutable, but you should extract data in appropriate way, as you don't have the whole RDD at your node.

---

Another possible issue (not in your case as you're using an immutable vector) is using mutable data inside `Point` iself, which is completely incorrect, so you'd lose all guarantees - the `RDD` itself is still gonna be immutable however.

Answer (score 0):

In order the RDD to be completely immutable, its content should be immutable as well:

```
scala> val m = Array.fill(2, 2)(0)
m: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(m)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Int]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1]
at parallelize at <console>:23

scala> rdd.collect()
res6: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> m(0)(1) = 2

scala> rdd.collect()
res8: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 2), Array(0, 0))
```

so because the Array is mutable, I could change it and therefore the RDD was updated with the new data