# How does rdd.cache works?

Tags: apache-spark

In the below code,  I have created an rdd, cached it and created child rdds out of it.  vertexRDD -> newVert1 -> newVert2 -> newVert3 -> newVert4 -> newVert5.  I do a simple incremental operation in each RDD.  
 
when cache is not enabled, the array values for newVert1, newVert2, newVert3 RDD are

```
0:ArrayBuffer(1, 0, 0, 0)  0:ArrayBuffer(2, 0, 0, 0)  0:ArrayBuffer(3, 0, 0, 0) 
1:ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 0, 0)  1:ArrayBuffer(0, 2, 0, 0)  1:ArrayBuffer(0, 3, 0, 0)
2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 1, 0)  2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 2, 0)  2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 3, 0)
3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 1)  3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 2)  3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 3)
```

But when the cache method is invoked on the parentRDD, the array values for newVert1, newVert2, newVert3 RDD are

```
0:ArrayBuffer(1, 0, 0, 0)  0:ArrayBuffer(3, 0, 0, 0)  0:ArrayBuffer(6, 0, 0, 0) 
1:ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 0, 0)  1:ArrayBuffer(0, 3, 0, 0)  1:ArrayBuffer(0, 6, 0, 0)
2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 1, 0)  2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 3, 0)  2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 6, 0)
3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 1)  3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 3)  3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 6)
```

It is something to do with foreach method on RDD.  This method is incrementing the values of Array elements.

I have posted the results in the code as comments. I have posted the results in the code as comments below each print statement.   Please help me in understanding the cache operation.  Thanks

```
package com.examples

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object ReCalculationModified {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("RecalculationModified")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val vertex = Array(
  (0, Array(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  (1, Array(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  (2, Array(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  (3, Array(0, 0, 0, 0)))

    val vertexRDD = sc.makeRDD(vertex).map(x => x).cache()
    val newVert1 = vertexRDD.map {
      case (vid, array) =>
        array(vid) += 1
        (vid, array)
    }
    println("--------------newVertex1-------------")
    newVert1.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))
    println("--------------VertexRDD-------------")
    vertexRDD.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))

    // Output of both vertexRDD and newVert1 is
    //      0:ArrayBuffer(1, 0, 0, 0)
    //      1:ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 0, 0)
    //      2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 1, 0)
    //      3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 1)   

    val newVert2 = newVert1.map {
      case (vid, array) =>
        array(vid) += 1
        (vid, array)
    }
    println("--------------newVertex2-------------")
    newVert2.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))
    println("--------------VertexRDD-------------")
    vertexRDD.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))

    // Output of both vertexRDD and newVert2 is
    //      0:ArrayBuffer(3, 0, 0, 0)
    //      1:ArrayBuffer(0, 3, 0, 0)
    //      2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 3, 0)
    //      3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 3)

     val newVert3 = newVert2.map {
      case (vid, array) =>
        array(vid) += 1
        (vid, array)
    }
    println("--------------newVertex3-------------")
    newVert3.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))
    println("--------------VertexRDD-------------")
    vertexRDD.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))

    // Output of both vertexRDD and newVert3 is
    //      0:ArrayBuffer(6, 0, 0, 0)
    //      1:ArrayBuffer(0, 6, 0, 0)
    //      2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 6, 0)
    //      3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 6)

         val newVert4 = newVert3.map {
      case (vid, array) =>
        array(vid) += 1
        (vid, array)
    }
    println("--------------newVertex4-------------")
    newVert4.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))
    println("--------------VertexRDD-------------")
    vertexRDD.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))

    // Output of both vertexRDD and newVert4 is
    //      0:ArrayBuffer(10, 0, 0, 0)
    //      1:ArrayBuffer(0, 10, 0, 0)
    //      2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 10, 0)
    //      3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 10)

    val newVert5 = newVert4.map {
      case (vid, array) =>
        array(vid) += 1
        (vid, array)
    }
    println("--------------newVertex5-------------")
    newVert5.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))
    println("--------------VertexRDD-------------")
    vertexRDD.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2.toBuffer))

    // Output of both vertexRDD and newVert5 is
    //      0:ArrayBuffer(15, 0, 0, 0)
    //      1:ArrayBuffer(0, 15, 0, 0)
    //      2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 15, 0)
    //      3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 15)  

  }
}
```

Comment: _"When cache method is not invoked, result is as expected and understandable but when the parent RDD is cached, I am unable to understand the result."_ could you explain what you mean by that? Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at these links which has some discussion on similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513894/apache-sparks-rddvector-immutability-issue, https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/18708/are-spark-rdd-really-mutable.html.

Comment: @Jacek - what I meant is the values in the array gets incremented by 1 for each child RDD.  The below is from newVert1 RDD                                                               0:ArrayBuffer(1, 0, 0, 0)
1:ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 0, 0)
2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 1, 0)
3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 1)

Comment: @Jacek - when cache is not enabled, the newVert3 has array values as  0:ArrayBuffer(3, 0, 0, 0) 1:ArrayBuffer(0, 3, 0, 0) 2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 3, 0) 3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 3)  and newVert5 will hold array values as  0:ArrayBuffer(5, 0, 0, 0) 1:ArrayBuffer(0, 5, 0, 0) 2:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 5, 0) 3:ArrayBuffer(0, 0, 0, 5).  But when the cache method is invoked on the parentRDD then the array values are  1, 3, 6, 10 and 15  for newVert1, newVert2, newVert3, newVert4 and newVert5 respectively for an increment by 1.  I have posted the results in the code as comments.  Thanks

Comment: @Kannan Edit your question and add the comments (before people vote to close the question as off topic).

Comment: Thanks Jacek.  I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The values are getting updated due to use of Array you had used. Arrays is mutable in Scala. See the below discussion.

[Why no immutable arrays in scala standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825702/why-no-immutable-arrays-in-scala-standard-library)

Also, `cache` is a transformation in Spark which caches an RDD in memory. Cache only avoids to run the DAG from starting. When cache is used, the processed data will be picked from the memory rather than going through the whole DAG and computing the same.

Caching is one of the features of Spark that makes it 10x to 100x faster than MapReduce

Comment: Thats fine.  I understand that cache saves the processed data.  Here,  array in vertexRDD is mutated by incrementing the array elements by 1.  Next a child RDD(newVert1) of vertexRDD increments by 1. Next child RDD (newVert2) of newVert1 is incremented by 1 but now the value is 3 and when the third child(newVert3) is incremented by 1, the result is different.  How is the increments calculated? I have posted the results as comments.